# How to display different subject rows in different Forms?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a [subject tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/create-manage-subject-tree?tabs=customerserviceadmincenter) as a case type on Case Entity

[image]

I want to display different subject rows in different Forms.
Like Form1 will display 'Client Services' and Form 2 will display say 'Credit' & 'Default Subject'.

Is it possible to do that?
Or Is there a way to apply a view to this field?

Answer (score 0):

Subject field is very limited in nature. Probably you have to think in PCF controls direction.

Some community tree controls and source code available in [PCF gallery](https://pcf.gallery/categories#tree), otherwise you can start a fresh control development.